# Como seleccionar un valor de un DropDownList en ASP.NET MVC con Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

Tengo 3 DropDownList que uno depende del otro. También tengo un campo DNI que al momento de colocar mi DNI, la mayoria de los otros campos se rellenan, pero con los DropDownList NO obtengo resultados, el campo departamento me coloca el valor de mi DNI, pero NO es seleccionado, y los otros DropDownList campos provincia y distrito NO SE CARGAN.

**He usado este codigo en Jquery y no obtuve resultado:**

```
$('#combo_departamento option[value="LIMA"]').attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
```

**Vista Interesado**

```
@model wsCharlas.Models.ClsInteresado

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inscripción";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Inscripción:</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<h4>Aquí usted podrá inscribirse a la charla respectiva que escogió.</h4>

    <hr />
    <strong>DATOS DEL PARTICIPANTE:</strong>
    <hr />

    <!--    <div class="form-horizontal"> -->
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dni_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dni_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_dni", @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dni_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.apePat_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.apePat_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_apePat", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.apePat_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.apeMat_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.apeMat_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_apeMat", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.apeMat_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nombres_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nombres_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_nombres", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nombres_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fecha_nac_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha_nac_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_fechNac", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha_nac_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.edad_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.edad_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_edad", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.edad_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_sexo", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.correo_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.correo_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_correo", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.correo_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.telefono_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.telefono_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_telefono", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.telefono_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.direccion_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.direccion_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_direccion", @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.direccion_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.depar_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.depar_Inter, (SelectList)ViewBag.Departamentos, "Seleccione un Departamento", new { @id = "campo_departamento", @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.provin_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.provin_Inter, (SelectList)ViewBag.Provincias, "Seleccione una Provincia", new { id = "campo_provincia", @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dist_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dist_Inter, (SelectList)ViewBag.Distritos, "Seleccione un Distrito", new { @id = "campo_distrito", @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <strong>DATOS DE LA CHARLA:</strong>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            <!--disabled = "true" -->
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID_charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = ViewBag.id, } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label">Charla:</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.titulo" disabled />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            <label class="control-label">Descripcion:</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.descripcion" disabled />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label">Fecha:</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.fecha" disabled />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label">Hora:</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.hora" disabled />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            <label class="control-label">Direccion:</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.direccion" disabled />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--</div>-->
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Regresar", "MostraCharlas", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#campo_departamento option:nth-child(1)').attr("value", "000");

        let dni = $("#campo_dni");
        let apePat = $("#campo_apePat");
        let apeMat = $("#campo_apeMat");
        let nombres = $("#campo_nombres");
        let fechNac = $("#campo_fechNac");
        let edad = $("#campo_edad");
        let sexo = $("#campo_sexo");
        let correo = $("#campo_correo");
        let telefono = $("#campo_telefono");
        let direccion = $("#campo_direccion");
        let departamento = $("#campo_departamento");
        let provincia = $("#campo_provincia");
        let distrito = $("#campo_distrito");

            function formInteresado() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ConsultarDNI", "Charlas")',
                data: { dni: dni.val()},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (rpta) {
                    apePat.val(rpta.apePat_Inter);
                    apeMat.val(rpta.apeMat_Inter);
                    nombres.val(rpta.nombres_Inter);
                    fechNac.val(rpta.fecha_nac_Inter);
                    edad.val(rpta.edad_Inter);
                    sexo.val(rpta.sexo_Inter);
                    correo.val(rpta.correo_Inter);
                    telefono.val(rpta.telefono_Inter);
                    direccion.val(rpta.direccion_Inter);
                    departamento.val(rpta.depar_Inter);
                    departamento.selectedIndex = 1;
                    //$('#campo_departamento option:nth-child(1)').attr("selected", "selected");
                    //provincia.val(rpta.provin_Inter);
                    // distrito.val(rpta.dist_Inter);
                },
                error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

        $("#campo_dni").focusout(function () {
            formInteresado();
        });

            //----------------

            function formProvincia() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ConsultarProvincias", "Charlas")',
                data: { depa: departamento.val()},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (rpta) {

                    $.each(rpta, function (index, element) {
                        $("#campo_provincia").append('<option value="' + element.Text + '">' + element.Text + '</option>');
                    });

                },
                error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

            $("#campo_departamento").change(function () {

                $('#campo_provincia option').remove();
                $('#campo_provincia').append("<option value='000'>Seleccione una Provincia</option>");

                $('#campo_distrito option').remove();
                $('#campo_distrito').append("<option value='000'>Seleccione un Distrito</option>");

                formProvincia();
        });

            //--------

            function formDistrito() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ConsultarDistritos", "Charlas")',
                data: { depa: departamento.val(), prov: provincia.val() },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (rpta) {

                    $.each(rpta, function (index, element) {
                        $("#campo_distrito").append('<option value="' + element.Text + '">' + element.Text + '</option>');
                    });

                },
                error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

            $("#campo_provincia").change(function () {
                $('#campo_distrito option').remove();
                $('#campo_distrito').append("<option value='000'>Seleccione un Distrito</option>");
                formDistrito();
        });


    });

    //-------------

    //$("#campo_departamento").val();
    //$("#campo_provincia").val();

</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 1:**

Cuando colocas tu DNI, solo me aparece mi ActionResult "ConsultarDNI", cuando en realidad debería aparecer "ConsultarDNI", "ConsultarProvincias" y "ConsultarDistritos"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2:**

Me acabo de dar cuenta que cuando selecciono un valor en cualquier DropDownList, no me genera ningún atributo selected, de seguro es por eso que no me funciona seleccionar un valor.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 3**

Aquí les dejo los 3 ActionResult que deben aparecer en mi aplicación web

**ConsultarDNI**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ConsultarDNI(string dni)
    {

        ServicesReniec.sConsultaDNISoapClient consultaDNI = new ServicesReniec.sConsultaDNISoapClient();
        List<string> resultado = new List<string>();
        resultado = consultaDNI.Consulta("JVEGA", dni);
        string ape_pat = "";
        string ape_mat = "";
        string nombres = "";
        string fech_nac = "";

        string edad = "";
        string sexo = "";
        string correo = "";
        string telefono = "";
        string direccion = "";

        string departamento = "";
        string provincia = "";
        string distrito = "";

        string ubigeo = "";
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string R in resultado)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    if ((R.Substring(0, 4) != "0000"))
                    {
                        //limpiarFormulario();
                        return Json(new ClsInteresado());
                    }

                    break;
                case 1:
                    ape_pat = R;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ape_mat = R;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    nombres = R;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    if (R.Equals(" "))
                    {
                        departamento = "CALLAO";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        departamento = R;
                    }

                    break;
                case 9:
                    provincia = R;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    distrito = R;
                    break;
                case 11:
                    direccion = R;
                    break;
                case 14:
                    sexo = R;
                    break;
                case 21:
                    fech_nac = R;
                    break;
            }
            i++;

        }

        ClsInteresado interesado = new ClsInteresado
        {
            apePat_Inter = ape_pat,
            apeMat_Inter = ape_mat,
            nombres_Inter = nombres,
            fecha_nac_Inter = fech_nac,
            edad_Inter = edad,
            sexo_Inter = sexo,
            correo_Inter = correo,
            telefono_Inter = telefono,
            direccion_Inter = direccion,
            depar_Inter = departamento,
            provin_Inter = provincia,
            dist_Inter = distrito
        };

        return Json(interesado);
    }
```

**ConsultarProvincias**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ConsultarProvincias(string depa)
        {
            string id_dept = MostrarID_Departamento(depa);

            return Json(new SelectList(listarProvincias(id_dept), "desc_prov", "desc_prov"));
        }
```

**ConsultarDistritos**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ConsultarDistritos(string depa, string prov)
    {

        string id_dept = MostrarID_Departamento(depa);
        string id_prov = MostrarID_Provincia(id_dept, prov);

        return Json(new SelectList(listarDistritos(id_dept, id_prov), "desc_dist", "desc_dist"));
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué te aparece en la pestaña de network? ¿Se generan las peticiones?

Comment: Me aparece solo mi ActionResult "ConsultarDNI", pero en realidad me deben aparecer 3 ActionResult.

Comment: prueba quiza con.. $('#combo_departamento").val('LIMA');...

Comment: Lo que me parece extraño es que al momento de seleccionar un valor de cualquier DropDownList NO ME APARECE EL ATRIBUTO "SELECTED"

Comment: No me funciono amigo @DiegoAvila

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar la secuencia de dependencias? Es decir, qué elementos dependen de otros.

Comment: Un distrito depende de una provincia para que cargue sus datos, y una provincia depende de un departamento para que cargue sus datos, y el departamento no depende de nadie.

Comment: ¿Algú motivo especial para definir las variables como LET en vez de VAR?

Comment: ninguno, solo lo implemento por buenas prácticas.

Comment: Acabo de usar el var y tampoco tuve exito, creo que debe ser por el selected

Comment: Por si acaso alguien sabrá el por qué no me genera el atributo "selected"?

Comment: Esto te será de utilidad: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95789/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-gian-franco-alexis-poma-vidal).

Answer (score 1):

Los Dropdownlist son muy quisquillosos en Razor
¿Puedes probar si te funciona esto?

```
$('#campo_provincia option:selected').val();
```

y/o

puedes definir tu DropDownList de esta manera y verificar que te seleccione el valor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dist_Inter,  new SelectList(@ViewBag.Distritos, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "campo_distrito" })
```